# Expansion of the relation between the cosmological growth factor and scale factor

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, dark-energy

Hello i'm studying large scale structure of the Universe (in $\Lambda$CDM Universe) using as time the growth factor defined by
$$ \ddot{D}+2H\dot{D}-4\pi G\bar{\rho}_{DM}D=0$$
in my equations i have the term $$\frac{1}{a^{\alpha+1}\dot{D}^2} \label{d}$$ which i would like to express in terms of only D, so giving the right expression also for $\dot{D}$. 
Previously I did a similar computation in a CDM universe using the scale factor a as time, which was much simpler, giving for the same term 
$$\frac{a^{-\alpha}}{a\dot{a}^2}=\frac{a^{-\alpha}}{a^3H^2}=\frac{a^{-\alpha}}{H_0^2\Omega_{0m}^2} \label{a}$$.
I would like to found a "similar" expression also for D. But I have no clue how to do it.
 I'm working for small values of a so I was thinking to expand the expression D(a) found in Doddleson Modern cosmology p214
$$D(a,\Omega_m)=\frac{5\Omega_m}{2(1-\Omega_m)}[\frac{3\sqrt{1+x}}{x^{3/2}}\log       (\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{x})+1+\frac{3}{x}]$$
where $x=\frac{1-\Omega_m}{\Omega_m}a$
then expanding for small x i found
$$D(a,\Omega_m)=\frac{5\Omega_m}{2(1-\Omega_m)}[\frac{3(1+x/2)}{x^{3/2}}\log       (1+x^2)+1+\frac{3}{x}]\sim \frac{15}{2}\frac{\Omega_m^2}{(1-\Omega_m)^2}\frac{1}{a}$$
which seems totally wrong because at early times we should have $D=a$. Someone have some idea how to find an expression for $\frac{1}{a^{\alpha+1}\dot{D}^2}$ similar to $\frac{a^{-\alpha}}{H_0^2\Omega_{0m}^2}$

Comment: What do you mean by *"in my equations"* Are you trying to solve $$\ddot{\delta} +2H\dot{\delta} - 4\pi G \rho \delta = 0$$ for  ? I mean I guess you are trying to find the perturbation in terms of matter density ?

Comment: @Reign i'm tryng to solve the fluid equations for studying large scale structure for baryons, this terms appears with the pressure

Comment: I am studying LSS as well. As you said at early times when fluctuations are small we have $\delta \propto a$ but I am.not familier with this expression